# Unlock my phone! March 2018

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, visual

New month, new password, but I've already forgotten! Help!

**What is my phone's password this month?**

[image]

Hint #1:

> As per usual, my password is pretty long (maybe around 40 digits?)

Hint #2:

> In March I took up an interest in analytical number theory

Comment: Really March? Really 2018?

Comment: If you look at my other puzzles you’ll see I’m starting January of 2018 and going month by month to the present day. Sorry for confusion!

Comment: Ah, OK. Fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your password is

> the first 40 digits, or perhaps decimal places, of the Euler-Mascheroni constant, sometimes denoted $\gamma$.

So it will begin

> either 5772 or 05772 or 0.5772.

Since

> to *41* decimal places the constant's value is 0.57721566490153286060651209008240243104215, the last digit will (if you've used 40 decimal places rather than 40 digits including the leading zero) depend on how you've chosen to round it.

Explanation in case the above doesn't make it clear:

> the *harmonic series* is $1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\cdots$ and the sum of its first $n$ terms is $\log n+\gamma+\varepsilon(n)$ where $\varepsilon(n)\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. So the limiting difference between the *harmonic* series and the *natural* logarithm is $\gamma$.

Comment: That was fast! Nice job!

Comment: The second hint made it pretty hard _not_ to get :-).

Comment: (Though I think I'd probably have got it quickly even without.)